# Find permutation that solves $\;\tau \circ X = \sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I need to find a permutation $X$ that solves $\;\tau \circ X = \sigma,\;$ given 
$$\tau = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 1
 \end{bmatrix} = (1,3,5)(2,4)$$
$$\sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 4
 \end{bmatrix} = (1,3)(2)(4,5)$$

Is there a trick on how to solve for $X$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: find the inverse of $\tau$ and left  "multiply" each side of the equation by $\tau^{-1}$ to solve for $X$.

Comment: $\tau^{-1} = (3,1,5)(4,2)$ so now I add $\sigma(3) = 1$ etc?

Comment: No, you want to left-multiply each side of the equation to isolate $X$:$$\tau^{-1}\circ \tau\circ X = \tau^{-1}\circ\sigma\iff X = \tau^{-1}\circ\sigma$$

Comment: $X = (1)(2,4,3,5)$

Comment: Yes, Chris, you've got it!

Comment: thanks alot. Sounds logic now.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you compose left to right:
$$\tau = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 1
 \end{bmatrix} = (1,3,5)(2,4)$$
times
$$X = \begin{bmatrix} 
3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 1\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 4
 \end{bmatrix} = (1,4,2,5)(3)$$
equals
$$\sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 4
 \end{bmatrix} = (1,3)(2)(4,5)$$